# Conditional query using form data as input

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I'm trying to execute a query using PHP and mongodb using inputs from a form.

```
<form method="post" action="search.php">
 <tr><td>Firm</td><td><input type="text" name="firm" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>City</td><td><input type="text" name="city" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td>State</td><td><input type="text" name="state" /></td></tr>
 <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Search" /></td></tr>
</form>
```

If all of the form fields are filled, I can do this easily (on the search.php page)

```
extract($_POST);
$query = array("firm" => $firm, "city" => $city, "state" => $state);
$fields = array("firm");
$cur = $collection->find($query,$fields);
```

But what if one or more of the fields is empty?  Is there an easy way to construct the query such that only non-empty fields are included?

Thanks,

mcdermott

Comment: What's your idea about how to do it? What did you try so far?

Comment: Sorry, I tried using if statements and array_push to append the query string, but that didn't seem to work. Like this, if(empty($firm)) $query = array_push($query, "firm" => $firm).  My quotes are likely messed up.

Comment: Why are PHP developers such a rowdy bunch?

Comment: @Will :) he isn't a PHP developer, he's a python guy ;)

Comment: You accepted my answer but you didn't upvote it, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
$query = array();

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    if (isValid($value))
    {
        $query[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

This way you just have to make sure that the form field names are the same as the field names of your data source. Of course you can do the validation before you loop over the already validated array.

Comment: Mind that you will have to write your own validation function isValid() which returns TRUE, if the input is valid and FALSE if it isn't.